# Clickable Image on customized actionbar in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying a way to have an image that is sitting on my actionbar as clickable. I mean I want to click on the image to open another class how do I do so?

Here is customized actionbar which I am setting it programatically onCreate.

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(actionBar.getDisplayOptions() | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(actionBar.getThemedContext());
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.logoonactionbar);
        ActionBar.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.END | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        layoutParams.rightMargin = 20;
        imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        actionBar.setCustomView(imageView);

        actionBar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.secondaryView));

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setIcon(android.R.color.transparent);
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.backgroundcolor)));
```

Is it possible, if so how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is actually Very simple
simply add Items in Menu.xml
here is example code of menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      android:showAsAction="never" />
```

and using this function you can perform operations on those buttons
here is the function code

```
@Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle presses on the action bar items
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_search:
        openSearch(); //Any function call or anything you want to perform
        return true;
    case R.id.action_settings:
        openSettings(); //Any function call or anything you want to perform
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
} }
```

for more detail follow the developers guide
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html

Comment: If I try this the image is coming up very small how do make it big? Is it possible?

Comment: you need to choose image with your desired size,
for this try to download some actionbar icon pack. its available in all sizes required for different screens.  @TheDevMan
https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html